# about setting up wireless router

Tags: wireless-router

Someone help me to setup the wireless router to share the network with roommates long time ago. Last week, for some reason, I turned off the router and then the network no longer works. Well, in my apartment, the WAN is available. If we connect the WAN with cable to the computers, we are able to surf the internet. But I remember at that time when someone help to setup the router, he said we are not allowed to directly use the wireless router (probably some policy of the building). So that's what he did (I don't exactly remember the procedures)

1) He plugged in the network from the wall to the WAN port of the wireless router with cable 2) He configured something so my laptop be able to surf the internet 3) He unplugged the WAN cable (which connected to the wall) and plug it into the LAN port of the wireless router 4) Then all laptops are able to wirelessly connected to the router to surf the internet

Well, I remember those procedures roughly but I fail to make the wireless network back. Any idea what to do to bring the network back?

I am using TP-LINK: TP-WRL841N

p.s. I know someone said I could have the cable go into the WAN port and share the network via the router, but if I do that, it will works for couples minutes and soon after the ip address will be blocked. I think that's policy of my building not to do in this way.

Comment: ask the guy to do the same thing again

Comment: he no longer work in the same city ... anyway if I can do that, I won't post this, thanks

Comment: Call your ISP then.

Answer (score 1):

@artistoex Probably best solution :)

Seriously:

```
      ,wire                                
W |  V         __\_____/__     .\  \  
A |====[WAN]==[WiFi Router]  ) ) )  ) ( ( (  [PC1]
L |            ¨¨¨¨¨H¨¨¨¨¨     ´/  /        
L |            ,->  H             ^   ( ( [PC2]        
  |     table ´    /H\  Microwaves´
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
               FLOOR
```

After that just configure WiFi Router to work as NAT / DHCP server. You might need to connect to router by wire while configuring it.

Search [Google](http://google.com/?q=Configure%20TP-Link%20TP-WRL841N) for configuring your router, there might also be downloadable manuals for it on manufacturer site. Possible router web configuration interface address for TP-Link is:  `http://192.168.1.1`

Comment: +1 Nice picture :-)  Maybe you should stress the point about NAT. Otherwise, great instruction.